# Add padding of Button doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a `Button` has fixed padding top and bottom, for example, 20dp.

But right now if I set `Button`'s padding:

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

The result is like:

**padding = 20dp + pink height**
[image]

What I expected:

**padding = 20dp**

[image]

**The problem is above/below the text `THIS IS A BUTTON`, the padding is 20dp + the pink area height.**

As you can see the green and blue view blocks are 20dp height. Then the two pink padding's seems are the default values. And even if I set 0dp for the padding, the pink spaces are still there.(As the bottom button)

Any way to remove the pink area's height to make the padding top/bottom of the text is just 20dp? Or what's the value of the pink height? (Seems top and bottom pink areas are not the same height) Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="This is a button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

Comment: What layouot are you using ? ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes, for some reason, it didn't show, I've edited it.

Comment: You want the red button same height with the green, and the bottom text same with blue?

Comment: yes, the top same as green, this is 20dp, same for bottom.

Comment: I would  suggest you to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: @JohnJoe Sorry, let me update a new image, I am misleading people. The blue and green block is just for clarification. Is nothing to do with my purpose.

Comment: @JohnJoe updated my image, thanks.

Comment: padding top and bottom should work in this case.  Can you show the last code of your image?

Comment: My code is just the Button right now. The image(green, blue, pink) is just I drew for making it clear. Only set padding_top then the value = 20dp + extra height.

Comment: ok, but how you know it is not 20dp after you have applied padding top and bottom?

Comment: Try to add a 20dp height view just on the right side as what I did(green, blue) stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="This is a button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view2">

    </View>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back_button">

    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="This is a button"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/back_button" />
```

Hope This Help...

Comment: Sorry I think you didn't get my question, I edited it. I want to remove the pink area height padding from the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Button class extends TextView** class and Button class sets some default padding to TextView.

### So, there can be two solutions

1. Create a custom class extending Button class(i.e.create custom button).
2. Use a TextView instead of button.(simple and what I prefer).

### Code snippet for using TextView like Button

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                android:background="@android:color/red"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="This is a button"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Do you know any way we can get the `default padding` value?

Comment: Hi @Rex50 Just checked replace by `TextView`, but the paddingTop/Bottom is the same effect as `Button`. Could you confirm this?

Comment: Are you using some custom fonts ? If that is the case then please check, the font itself might have default padding.

Comment: I just figured out that in my answer I have used style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" which will take button's style and apply to the TextView. So try removing it and let me know if it works so that I can edit my answer.